# Making a Betting Site Roulette

Tags: javascript, reactjs

During this lockdown time, I've been programming a Betting Site using React Framework to improve my programming skills. I've been doing great until to the point of coding the actual roulette. At first, I tried using @keyframes using the translateX() function (the wheel is a background-image and spins sideways btw).
I coded so every time I clicked a button the wheel spun for testing purposes. But it was not good enough, because the round result is generated in the backend and the amount the wheel translates is retrieved from the server, so the translateX() needs to have dynamic values. I created another post asking how I could dynamically set the value of the translateX() function so it could land in the right number. Turns out it's more complex than that. Take https://csgoempire.com as an example. I was taking a look at the code and in the roulette HTML code, I realized that the change the background-position with `element.style.setProperty()`

[image: Text]

In this website the wheel spin is smooth. Since I'm a considerably new to web programming and using NodeJs, CSS, HTML, and ReactJs I'm not sure how they did this. I'm using sockets on my project to establish a connection between the server and the clients, in a way that everyone can see the same thing at the same time. So I assume I need to make this spin function server-side and pass the background-position to the client every tick, but I don't know if this can cause lag or not. I've been also trying to create a function that does that, but it's quite difficult since I haven't learned this type of math yet. (I'm in the 9th grade)

[image: Text]

That's the function I thought that would work. At first, the speed of the roulette spin is constant and at a certain point, it starts to decrease creating a smooth effect. The speed represents the amount of pixels the background-image moves per time. The problem is that I don't know to create this function and I don't know if this is the right solution. What should I do? Thanks in advance! PS: Sorry for any spelling mistake or any trouble understanding what I said in this post. English is not my native language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your function is incorrect, it should slow down fast at the beginning then slowly at the end until it stops. An easy function for that is: f(x+1) = f(x)*k where k is smaller than 1 (for example 0.96).

The smaller the value of k, the faster it will stop. Since this simple function is infinite, you should add a test in the loop to detect when it's not moving anymore and then exit the loop and give the result.

Comment: ok, thank you! I'll use that, but do you have any idea of the rest of the question, like how can I implement this?

Comment: You could compute the sequence in an array on the server and send that sequence to the clients so they can replay it. For example [100, 70, 50, 40, 35, 28, 22, 19, ...]

Comment: Alright, just you more question what should be f(x)? I just didn't get that, what function should it be, quadratic or something else??

Comment: f(x) is the amount of translation performed at each step of the animation. Let's say you want to start the spinning with a first translation of 100px, then the second translation will be100*0.96 = 96px, then the next will be 96*0.96=92.16px and so on

Comment: When you calculate the spinning sequence, make sure to set the starting speed (ie first translation) to a random number (within a certain range), so that nobody can predict where your roulette will stop

Comment: That won't be a problem. The spinning only happens when the bet time finishes so there's no problem if they know because they won't be able to bet anyway